# Classifier-independent feature selection before spliting?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I need to use the information gain feature selection method in my dataset. However, I was told that using it before spliting the data will lead to data leakage and a biased result.

I read a lot about this, but I still not getting it (I guess). The articles that I read only talked about it generally, and the examples were always using wrapper/embedded methods, could not find one example using the method I need.

So the question is, since information gain is ***classifier-independent***, using it in the complete dataset before splitting will still lead to information leakage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory it's quite simple. You have to build your classifier without any knowledge about your testing set. Pretend it doesn't exist. You are not even allowed to peek at it, as a human, before you select a classifier and all its (hyper-)parameters. In practice, how bad it is depends on how much information you use.

But if you use features that were selected by using statistics over the testing set, your classifier will (on average) do slightly better on the testing set than if you hadn't used this information.

So your testing set is no longer suited to measure the performance without bias. You should expect your classifier to do slightly worse on real data, compared to the testing set. Although it will do better than if you hadn't "cheated", because it has been trained using more data.

Comment: Thank you! So, for example, I used information gain before spliting my data, the data that went to the algorithm for calculating the information gain wasn't classified at all, it was just a bunch of data toguether without any clasification. So in this case I can assume that my data, after the feature selection, went to my classifier without being "cheated"?.

Comment: Suppose you have 500 features but only 6 data points: 3 for training and 3 for testing. Features selection picks just one feature, your classifier is very simple. It will obviously perform well on the testing set, if you selected features based on the testing set, and much worse in reality.